# Plot 2 bars in the same graph

Tags: r

Let's say I have a sample dataset that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(cat = letters[1:5], val1 = sample(1:10, 5), val2 = sample(1:10, 5))
```

I want to plot a bar graph with cat in the x axis, and for each cat, compare the two values with separate bars close to each other.
What I want is something that looks like this
[image]

Comment: `position = "dodge"` is the key here.

Comment: `df %>%
  gather(key, value, -cat) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(cat, value, fill = key) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
`